# Django - How can I distinguish what item I want to get deleted?

Tags: python, django

So I have several items (notes as I call them) saved in a database and displayed in a page like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZNmR.jpg

I want to be able to edit and delete a specific note but I'm having difficulties to know how can I tell my view which one I want to delete/edit

I had to do similar things before but before I always was able to change my url so I would just pass the id through there, so now that I stay in the same page I really don't know what to do

views.py

```
def delete_note(request, pk):
note = get_object_or_404(Notes, id=pk)
note.delete()
return redirect('notes')
```

template

```
    <div class="container">
    <div>
        <h1>Notes <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#2modal" style="float: right; margin-left: 15px; color: white" type="button" name="button">New note</button> </h1>
    </div>
     {% for nt in note %}
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">
                {{ nt.username }}
            </h5>
            <p class="card-text">
                {{ nt.text }}
            </p>
            <b>
                {{ nt.date }}
            </b>
            <div style="float: right">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="float: right; margin-left: 15px; color: white" type="button" name="button"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
         <!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Warning!</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
          <p><strong>You are about to delete this note </strong></p>
          <p>Are you sure you want to delete it?</p>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" style="float: left;">Close</button>
          <form action="{% url 'delete_note' nt.id %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
         {% csrf_token %}
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="delete" value="Delete">
                  </form>
```

url

```
path('<int:pk>/delete/note/', delete_note, name="delete_note"),
```

model

```
class Notes(models.Model):
username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
date = models.CharField(max_length=30)
text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Comment: In general, you should have different views for "add", "edit/update" and "delete". The latter two should point to a url where the <id> of the object to be updated/deleted is included, whereas the first on ("add") doesn't. So write a different view function for the delete action, with its own url pattern.

Comment: Explain exactly what should happen when the user clicks "edit" or "delete". There isn't any form shown in your template where the user can input or change information and it's not clear what you mean by "stay in the same page". Same for adding a new item, what happens when the user clicks on "new note"?

Comment: So I created another view and added a key that auto increments to use it as a primary key, I'm not sure is how to call this new view
`
def delete_note(request, pk):
    note = get_object_or_404(Notes, sn=pk)
    note.delete()
    return redirect('notes')
`

Comment: `{% url 'your-pattern-name' pk=note.pk %}` in your template for the delete form. This is assuming you created a url pattern with the pk in it and have a `note` object in the template.

Comment: Updated the post with tht code
Not sure what to add in the url and dunno if this is right

Comment: your pattern name is `delete_note` so use that in the {% url %}

Comment: Note that you must embed the delete button as a "submit" button in a `<form method="post" action="{% url 'delete_note' note.id %}">` so you POST your delete action rather than GET. It's never a good idea to have actions that change the database state in a GET request. Change your view to check that `request.method == 'POST'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never delete anything based on a GET request. So don't make a simple `<a>` tag button to cause a deletion of your note. You need to put your delete action in a form that gets submitted with a POST request.

Change your template to:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'delete_note' note.pk %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="delete">DELETE</input>
</form>
```

Also you should give each modal a different id, now when you click the trash can icon, the target is "#myModal" but that's always the first one since ids have to be unique. Add the forloop counter or the pk to the id.

And your view to:

```
def delete_note(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.get('delete'):
        note = get_object_or_404(Notes, pk=pk)
        note.delete()
        return redirect('notes')
    else:
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed(['DELETE'])
```

Note also that a better url, that would better follow REST guidelines, would be:

```
path('notes/<int:pk>/delete', delete_note, name="delete_note")
```

because "/notes/" is the list of notes, "/notes/id" is a specific note and "/notes/id/delete" is the delete action on the specific note (in a real REST API you wouldn't need /delete but would just send a `DELETE` HTTP request to "/notes/id", but that cannot be done in a browser that only supports `POST`).

Comment: getting this error: django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'delete_note' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/delete\\/note\\/$']

Comment: That means `note.id` wasn't defined. How are you defining `note`? Do you have `{% for note in notes %}` or something like that? You showed us a list of notes being rendered in your template, how do you do that?

Comment: One thing, the notes are like this: https://imgur.com/a/lZa3FWq but when I delete one, the one it gets deleted is the one at the top of the notes, regardless of what delete button I click, the id is an AutoField so it's getting incremented everytime a new post is created. As the id is being pass in the for in the url I would assume that each note is getting associated with it's respective id.

Comment: something you said is strange. You should not have to add an AutoField, django does that automatically for you (it's called the 'id'). I was assuming your pk and id were the same, but then somewhere you used `sn` which I have no idea what it is. Just make sure the pk you use in the template is the same as the pk you query on in the view. I've changed the answer to reflect this (using `pk` everywhere). You can also use another unique field (e.g. a `slug`) but then you need to replace that everywhere.

Comment: Yea the sn was just a type (one of the variables I used the most was called sn), I changed it already to id, even tho this problem won't disappear

Comment: Just look in your HTML source in your browser dev tools to see what URL is set as "action" for each of your notes.

Comment: It's really weird cause the id is different on each one (they are now in a modal) but it still deletes the the one on the top https://imgur.com/a/4j9KMVL

Comment: Show the HTML of the form **including the actual delete button**.

Comment: All your modals have the same id, so when you click the trash icon you always open the first one. Instead of "you are about to delete this note." print "you are about to delete the note by {{ nt.username }} submitted on {{ nt.date }}" then you'll be able to verify which note you're about to delete.

Comment: Yea I changed the id to the id and everything is now working perfectly, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the note id as another parameter in your form. You can use a hidden input inside your html form and use the note.id as value.

Comment: That's bad practice. Use different views to handle the different cases. Django doesn't have a `CreateView`, `UpdateView` and `DeleteView` for nothing.